# Setinterval is not working properly

Tags: php, jquery

If i use setinterval with strings then it works fine,but it also  loads the chat related to prvious id(cityid) set by onclick. and secreen shuffles after every second between chat related to new id(cityid) on new click and previous id.I want to stop the timer if it is running by previous id,and fetch only chat related to new id,so that new chat only related to new id will b shown.

Plz help,any alternative approach will also be appretiated.

Php onclick is here

```
            echo "<A href='#'  onclick=allccityid('$comid','$comname',$cityid,'$cities');>$cities</A><br> ";
```

Jquery code is here.

```
function all(comid,comname,cityid,cname){
//clearInterval(si);

 setInterval('chatcom_load('+ comid +','+ cityid +');', 1000)

 }


 function chatcom_load(idi, cityida) {

$.post('sendchat2.php', {option:'chatcom_load', tocom:idi, tocity:cityida}, function(data) {
    $('#chatcom #commid #commidwin').html(data);

});
}
```

However I also try  the setinterval by this way,but it did not work(refresh).I must  have to pass Two parameters to the chatcom_load function.

```
setInterval(chatcom_load(comid, cityid), 1000)
```

Answer (score 4):

```
setInterval(chatcom_load(comid, cityid),
```

This calls the `chatcom_load` function *immediately*, then passes the result to `setInterval`.

You need to pass a function to `setInterval`, like this:

```
setInterval(function() { chatcom_load(comid, cityid); },
```

Comment: Also need to add a reference to the `setInterval()` so that it can be cancelled and restarted for the new values.

Comment: @doublesharp ,Thanks for quick response,How can i cancel it and restart for the new values.this is my main question?

Comment: @SidraNaeem See my answer - you need to reference the result of `setInterval` in a global variable to be able to clear it

Answer (score 0):

`setInterval()` only takes a function call, your code is executing the method and passing the result. You need to wrap your method in a `function(){}`. You will also need to reference the current interval and cancel it if it has been set to prevent the former values from continuing to load:

```
var si;
function all(comid,comname,cityid,cname){
    if (si) clearInterval(si);
    si = setInterval(function(){ chatcom_load(comid, cityid); }, 1000);
}
```

Comment: ,thank you,it works fine,but now speed to fetch the chat is very slow.it takes longer time to update the chat window.whole chat system is now seems very heavy.

Comment: That might necessitate a new question - there are a lot of reasons why your chat system might run slowly...